# Solution Verification: Given $|A\cup B|=45, |A|=30,$ and $|A\cap B|=7,$ find $|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> Given |A∪B|=45, |A|=30, and |A∩B|=7, find |B|.

If I am not mistaken here is how I am reading the scenario:

B must have 22 elements.  The 7 that it shares with A, and then 15 of its own unique elements.

23 unique to A, 7 shared by both, and 15 unique to B.

23 + 7 + 15 = 45. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a cool identity you can use here:

$$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$
$$ \Longrightarrow 45 = 30 + |B| - 7$$
$$ \therefore |B| = 22$$

The identity makes sense if you think about: we subtract the intersection at the end, so we don't double-count the elements that are common to both $B$ and $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed, you are correct in reasoning the problem out, and you arrived at precisely the correct answer, for the right reasons.

It's good to understand how/why the identity posted by Newb works, and you seem to have understood the how and the why, as far as it applies here. Nice work!

$$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| \iff |B| = |A\cup B| - |A| + \underbrace{|A\cap B|}_{\text{shared}}$$

Comment: You have a mistake there. **EDIT:** Now it's gone!

Comment: @Asaf I think I need coffee before and with my dinner! ;-)

Comment: Try beer, works better. (Note that you can't write "better" without "beer"... and "double tea".)

Comment: @amWhy, we all know the saying attributed to Erdos. And coffee was often not enough for him  :-)

Comment: @Asaf Hehehehe. :D. I think you're right, my friend!